# EF null SQL database

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Can anyone help me with Entity Framework?

This is my model class:

[image]

but whenever I tried creating the script out of it `Script-Migration`, the `PrimaryAssignedTo` is showing `NOT NULL`:

[image]

Comment: Change `PrimaryAssignedTo` from `int` to `int?`. All non-nullable class properties are implicitly `[Required]` because you cannot have `int x = null` in C#, hence why you need to use `int?` (or `Nullable<Int32>`).

Comment: I have a question on that, I tried it out changed my code after changing I tried running "Add-Migration" since my table already exists unfortunately the ef file it produce has no code in the Up

Comment: Ooops nvm the Nullable<Int32> has produce an UP compare to the adding a questionmark